# How to create a pie chart with business hours

Tags: charts, kibana, elastic-stack

I have a list of `docs` in my ELK stack, and I need to create a pie chart with percentile of docs that were created in business hours (in my case 7 to 16) and free hours (17 to 6).

But, when I try to use these ranges, the chart does not work (of course), 100% of chart is filled by first range.

[image].

So, I need to split graph in 3 ranges.

- 0-6 (free hours)
- 7-16 (business hours)
- 17-23 (free hours)

[image]

But it is not ideal, it is very confuse.

How can I join two free hours ranges in one??